# python string slicer issue

Tags: python, string

Hi Everyone I'm trying to design a code which takes a product code from the user and then slices into two parts, they key part is the first one, because the first part from index 0 to 3(not including 3 though) must be in capital Letters.
So I created this code:

```
code=input("Enter a product code: ")


def test(code):
    set1=test[0 : 3]
    set2=test[3 : 8]

    if set1.isupper():
        print("Correct Code")


test(code)
```

Now the issue with this code is that when I ran it I got this error:

```
    set1=test[0 : 3]
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Anyone know why this error keeps coming up? I simply inputted a bogus value like: HHHH343GG3 and yet it happens,

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `set1=test[0 : 3]` instead of `set1=code[0 : 3]`.

`code` is the parameter being passed in, `test` is the name of the function that you are calling:

```
>>> test
<function test at 0x1003bcae8>
>>> code
'foo'
>>> test[0:3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
>>> code[0:3]
'foo'
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
code=input("Enter a product code: ")

def test(code):
    set1=code[0 : 3]
    set2=code[3 : 8]
    if set1.isupper():
        print("Correct Code")

test(code)
```